# Can biological quantum processes be used to guide optimized quantum algorithms?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-biology, biocomputing

My question is a continuation from the previous question:[Is Quantum Biocomputing ahead of us?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/is-quantum-biocomputing-ahead-of-us). Considering that there exist many biological processes with a quantum nature present (Photosynthesis, Electron transport chain, etc). And, since this biological quantum processes are quite optimal in terms of efficiency and yield:

I am wondering if these could be mimicked by engineers/scientists to improve the actual possibilities in quantum computation. Let me explain a bit deeper my question: Nature is extremely efficient. Especially intracellular processes are well optimized in both time and space this, with their high yield, can be studied in order to check the properties/structural features that contribute to such efficiency. Please note that I am not suggesting or asking about the possibility of using directly biological molecules or processes but to try to extract what makes them ultra-efficient and used such knowledge in the design of particular architectures.
My question is related to this, is that an actual field of research? are we now dealing with the 'natural quantum processes imitation'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, if there is an actual field of research, [Quantum Information Biology (QIB)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02515) seems to fit what you are looking for.

Once [a textbook has been written](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10701-015-9929-y) on a subject I think it is fair to classify it as a valid research field. Also you may consider [the controversial Penrose–Hameroff ‘Orch OR‘ model](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/356/1743/1869) to fall into this category, and maybe even the no less controversial research on [Quantum Cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cognition).

But you seem to be most interested in learning from biology for QIS which is what [the Oxford Martin Programme on Bio-Inspired Quantum Technologies](https://www.oxfordmartin.ox.ac.uk/research/programmes/quantum) is investigating. **A word of caution though**, if you look at [their publications](https://www.oxfordmartin.ox.ac.uk/research/programmes/quantum/publications) they appear to be mostly [Quantum Biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_biology). To my knowledge no actual Quantum Information processing has been experimentally demonstrated to take place in biological systems.

And while there is no doubt that engineering and technology can often been inspired, and improved upon, by mimicking biology, I don't think this hypothesis is necessarily a foregone conclusion when it comes to quantum computing or quantum technologies.

Take photosynthesis for example. It is an incredibly well working process, arguably the most important life sustaining one on earth, but as you can tell from the color of leafs it only uses a small part of the sun light's spectrum. That is why [it is not very efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_efficiency). It only converts 3%-6% of the incoming light to energy that can be used by the plant. The best solar cells are pushing beyond 40% efficiency.

So while these research fields are widely exciting, I don't see Quantum Biocomputing to happen anytime soon.